# Finding first index of where value in column B is greater than a value in column A

Tags: python-polars

I'd like to know the first occurrence (index) when a value in column A is greater than in column B. Currently I use a for loop (and it's super slow) but I'd imagine it's possible to do that in a rolling window.

```py
df = polars.DataFrame({"idx": [i for i in range(5)], "col_a": [1,2,3,4,4], "col_b": [1,1,5,5,3]})

# apply some window function?

# result of first indices where a value in column B is greater than the value in column A
result = polars.Series([2,2,2,3,None])
```

I'm still trying to understand polars concept of windows but I imagine the pseudo code would look sth like this:

1. for window length compare values in both columns, use `arg_min()` to get the index
2. if the resulting index is not found (e.g. value None or 0), increase window length and make a second pass
3. make passes until some max window_len

Current `for` loop implementation:

```py
df = polars.DataFrame({"col_a": [1,2,3,4,4], "col_b": [1,1,5,5,3]})

for i in range(0, df.shape[0]):
    # `arg_max()` returns 0 when there's no such index or if the index is actually 0
    series = (df.select("col_a")[i,0] < df.select("col_b")[i:])[:,0]
    idx_found = True in series
    
    if idx_found:
        print(i + series.arg_max())
    else:
        print("None")

# output:
2
2
2
3
None
```

Edit 1:

This almost solves the problem. But we still don't know if `arg_max` found an actual `True` value or didn't found an index since it returns `0` for both cases.

One idea is that we're never satisfied with the answer `0` and make a second scan for all values where the result was `0` but now with a longer window.

```py
df.select(polars.col("idx")) + \
df_res = df.groupby_dynamic("idx", every="1i", period="5i").agg(
    [
       (polars.col("col_a").head(1) < polars.col("col_b")).arg_max().alias("res")
    ]
)
```

Edit 2:

This is the final solution: the first pass is made from the code in `Edit 1`. The following passes (with increasingly wider windows/periods) can be made with:

```py
increase_window_size = "10i"
df_res.groupby_dynamic("idx", every="1i", period=increase_window_size).agg(
    [
       (polars.col("col_a").head(1) < polars.col("col_b")).filter(polars.col("res").head(1) == 0).arg_max().alias("res")
    ]
)
```

Comment: Your question doesn't match your result.  The first time col_a is bigger than col_b is at idx 1 but your result is a series not a single value.

Comment: agree, your `result` doesn't match what you describe as your expected output. please show the loop you've written

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, changed col A to B. Hope it makes sense now.

Comment: not really TBH - could you show your code please?

Comment: Edit: added the case for `None` - no such index found

Answer (score 0):

Starting from...

```
df=pl.DataFrame({"idx": [i for i in range(5)], "col_a": [1,2,3,4,4], "col_b": [1,1,5,5,3]})
```

For each row, you want the min `idx` where the current row's `col_a` is less than every subsequent row's `col_b`.

The first step is to add two columns that will contain all the data as a list and then we want to `explode` those into a much longer DataFrame.

```
df.with_columns([
    pl.col('col_b').list(), 
    pl.col('idx').list().alias('b_indx')]) \
        .explode(['col_b','b_indx'])
```

From here, we want to apply a filter so we're only keeping rows where the `b_indx` is at least as big as the `idx` AND the `col_a` is less than `col_b`

```
df.with_columns([
    pl.col('col_b').list(), 
    pl.col('idx').list().alias('b_indx')]) \
        .explode(['col_b','b_indx']) \
.filter((pl.col('b_indx')>=pl.col('idx')) & (pl.col('col_a')<pl.col('col_b')))
```

There are a couple ways you could clean that up, one is to `groupby`+`agg`+`sort`

```
df.with_columns([
    pl.col('col_b').list(), 
    pl.col('idx').list().alias('b_indx')]) \
        .explode(['col_b','b_indx']) \
.filter((pl.col('b_indx')>=pl.col('idx')) & (pl.col('col_a')<pl.col('col_b'))) \
.groupby(['idx']).agg([pl.col('b_indx').min()]).sort('idx')
```

The other way is to just do `unique` by `idx`

```
df.with_columns([
    pl.col('col_b').list(), 
    pl.col('idx').list().alias('b_indx')]) \
        .explode(['col_b','b_indx']) \
.filter((pl.col('b_indx')>=pl.col('idx')) & (pl.col('col_a')<pl.col('col_b'))) \
.unique(subset='idx')
```

Lastly, to get the null values back you have to join it back to the original df.  To keep with the theme of adding to the end of the chain we'd want a right join but right joins aren't an option so we have to put the join back at the beginning.

```
df.join(
    df.with_columns([
        pl.col('col_b').list(), 
        pl.col('idx').list().alias('b_indx')]) \
            .explode(['col_b','b_indx']) \
    .filter((pl.col('b_indx')>=pl.col('idx')) & (pl.col('col_a')<pl.col('col_b'))) \
    .unique(subset='idx'),
on='idx',how='left').get_column('b_indx')

shape: (5,)
Series: 'b_indx' [i64]
[
    2
    2
    2
    3
    null
]
```

**Note:**

I was curious on the performance difference between my approach and jqurious's approach so I did

```
df=pl.DataFrame({'col_a':np.random.randint(1,10,10000), 'col_b':np.random.randint(1,10,10000)}).with_row_count('idx')
```

then ran each code chunk.  Mine took 1.7s while jqurious's took just 0.7s BUT his answer isn't correct...

For instance...

```
df.join(
    df.with_columns([
        pl.col('col_b').list(), 
        pl.col('idx').list().alias('b_indx')]) \
            .explode(['col_b','b_indx']) \
    .filter((pl.col('b_indx')>=pl.col('idx')) & (pl.col('col_a')<pl.col('col_b'))) \
    .unique(subset='idx'),
on='idx',how='left').select(['idx','col_a','col_b',pl.col('b_indx').alias('result')]).head(5)
```

yields...

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬────────┐
│ idx ┆ col_a ┆ col_b ┆ result │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ u32 ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ u32    │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 4     ┆ 1     ┆ 2      │ 4<5 at indx2
│ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ 4     ┆ 1      │ 1<4 at indx1
│ 2   ┆ 3     ┆ 5     ┆ 2      │ 3<5 at indx2
│ 3   ┆ 4     ┆ 2     ┆ 5      │ off the page
│ 4   ┆ 5     ┆ 4     ┆ 5      │ off the page
└─────┴───────┴───────┴────────┘
```

whereas

```
df.with_columns(
pl.when(pl.col("col_a") < pl.col("col_b"))
    .then(1)
    .cumsum()
    .backward_fill()
    .alias("result") + 1
).head(5)
```

yields

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌─────┬───────┬───────┬────────┐
│ idx ┆ col_a ┆ col_b ┆ result │
│ --- ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ u32 ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i32    │
╞═════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 0   ┆ 4     ┆ 1     ┆ 2      │ 4<5 at indx2
│ 1   ┆ 1     ┆ 4     ┆ 2      │ not right
│ 2   ┆ 3     ┆ 5     ┆ 3      │ not right
│ 3   ┆ 4     ┆ 2     ┆ 4      │ off the page
│ 4   ┆ 5     ┆ 4     ┆ 4      │ off the page
└─────┴───────┴───────┴────────┘
```

**Performance**

This scales pretty terribly, bumping the df from 10,000 rows to 100,000 made my kernel crash.  Going from 10,000 to 20,000 made it take 5.7s which makes sense since we're squaring the size of the df.  To mitigate this, you can do overlapping chunks.

First let's make a function

```
def idx_finder(df):
    return(df.join(
    df.with_columns([
        pl.col('col_b').list(), 
        pl.col('idx').list().alias('b_indx')]) \
            .explode(['col_b','b_indx']) \
    .filter((pl.col('b_indx')>=pl.col('idx')) & (pl.col('col_a')<pl.col('col_b'))) \
    .unique(subset='idx'),
on='idx',how='left').select(['idx','col_a','col_b',pl.col('b_indx').alias('result')]))
```

Let's get some summary stats:

```
print(df.select(pl.all().max()) )

shape: (9, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ col_a ┆ col_b │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ 1     ┆ 9     │
│ 2     ┆ 9     │
│ 3     ┆ 9     │
│ 4     ┆ 9     │
│ ...   ┆ ...   │
│ 6     ┆ 9     │
│ 7     ┆ 9     │
│ 8     ┆ 9     │
│ 9     ┆ 9     │
└───────┴───────┘
```

This tells us that for any value of `col_a` what the biggest value of `col_b` is 9 which means anytime the `result` is null when `col_a` is 9 that it's a true null

With that, we do

```
chunks=[]
chunks.append(idx_finder(df[0:10000])) # arbitrarily picking 10,000 per chunk
```

Then take a look at

```
chunks[-1].filter((pl.col('result').is_null()) & (pl.col('col_a')<9))

shape: (2, 4)
┌──────┬───────┬───────┬────────┐
│ idx  ┆ col_a ┆ col_b ┆ result │
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---    │
│ u32  ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ u32    │
╞══════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════╡
│ 9993 ┆ 8     ┆ 6     ┆ null   │
│ 9999 ┆ 3     ┆ 1     ┆ null   │
└──────┴───────┴───────┴────────┘
```

Let's cutoff this chunk at idx=9992 and then start the next chunk at 9993

```
curindx=chunks[-1].filter((pl.col('result').is_null()) & (pl.col('col_a')<9))[0,0]
chunks[-1]=chunks[-1].filter(pl.col('idx')<curindx)
```

With that we can reformulate this logic into a while loop

```
curindx=0
chunks=[]
while curindx<=df.shape[0]:
    print(curindx)
    chunks.append(idx_finder(df[curindx:(curindx+10000)]))
    curchunkfilt=chunks[-1].filter((pl.col('result').is_null()) & (pl.col('col_a')<9))
    if curchunkfilt.shape[0]==0:
        curindx+=10000
    elif curchunkfilt[0,0]>curindx:
        curindx=chunks[-1].filter((pl.col('result').is_null()) & (pl.col('col_a')<9))[0,0]
    else:
        print("curindx not advancing")
        break
    chunks[-1]=chunks[-1].filter(pl.col('idx')<curindx)
```

Finally just

```
pl.concat(chunks)
```

**As long as we're looping here's another approach**

If the gaps between the A/B matches are small then this will end up being fast as it scales according to the gap size rather than by the size of the df.  It just uses `shift`

```
df=df.with_columns(pl.lit(None).alias('result'))
y=0
while True:
    print(y)
    maxB=df.filter(pl.col('result').is_null()).select(pl.col('col_b').max())[0,0]
    df=df.with_columns((
        pl.when(
            (pl.col('result').is_null()) & (pl.col('col_a')<pl.col('col_b').shift(-y))
        ).then(pl.col('idx').shift(-y)).otherwise(pl.col('result'))).alias('result'))
    y+=1
    if df.filter((pl.col('result').is_null()) & (pl.col('col_a')<maxB) & ~(pl.col('col_b').shift(-y).is_null())).shape[0]==0:
        break
```

With my random data of 1.2m rows it only took 2.6s with a max row offset of 86.  If, in your real data, the gaps are on the order of, let's just say, 100,000 then it'd be close to an hour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It really helps understanding the `polars` way. Just ran your example on my 1.2M row data frame. Computer went OOM after using +200GB of memory :). Really appreciate your answer though!

Comment: @trytt check my last update.  You'll need to dynamically set the col_b < 9 logic and you may need to reset that on a rolling basis depending on your actual data but it should work.  It took about 2min on my computer with a 1.2m row df

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Apologies if I caused you to waste time benchmarking against my approach. I completely missed the part about searching forward for the next largest value. I thought they were just comparing the values in each row.