# Create a new column with the first value that matches a condition

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have a Dataframe similar to this:

```
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'Time': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'Value': [100, 75, 70, 105, 140, 220, 65, 180, 150]
})
```

Represented here:

```
|  Time  | Value  | 
|   1    |   100  | 
|   2    |    75  |
|   3    |    70  |
|   4    |   105  |
|   5    |   140  |
|   6    |   220  |
|   7    |    65  |
|   8    |   180  |
|   9    |   150  |
```

(Note that it comes sorted by `Time`)

I need to create a new column named `NewColumn`, that would yield the next `Time` where `Value` is lower than current `Value`.

**EDIT:** it is important to specify that my original dataset has more than 10 millions of lines, and even though the original requirement is the one above, it is fair to say that some operations could end up exceeding RAM very quickly. To balance this, it would be acceptable to introduce a lookahead limit to test the original condition. For example it would be acceptable to yield the next `Time` where `Value` is lower than current `Value` **up to the next 100 `Time`**

Something like this:

```
|  Time  | Value  | NewColumn |
|   1    |   100  |       2   | >> next Time with Value lower than 100
|   2    |    75  |       3   | >> next Time with Value lower than 75
|   3    |    70  |       7   | >> next Time with Value lower than 70
|   4    |   105  |       7   | >> next Time with Value lower than 105
|   5    |   140  |       7   | >> next Time with Value lower than 140
|   6    |   220  |       7   | >> next Time with Value lower than 220
|   7    |    65  |    null   | >> next Time with Value lower than 65
|   8    |   180  |       9   | >> next Time with Value lower than 180
|   9    |   150  |    null   | >> next Time with Value lower than 150
```

So far, my approach have been to try to create a new temporary column that would hold a slice of `Value` from the next row up to last row, like this:

```
|  Time  | Value  |  Slice_of_Value   | 
|   1    |   100  | [75, 70, … 150]   | 
|   2    |    75  | [70, 105, … 150]  |
|   3    |    70  | [105, 140, … 150] |
|   4    |   105  | [140, 220, … 150] |
|   5    |   140  | [220, 65, … 150]  |
|   6    |   220  | [65, 180, 150]    |
|   7    |    65  | [180, 150]        |
|   8    |   180  | [150]             |
|   9    |   150  | []                |
```

Then try to infer the position of the first match satisfying the condition: "lower than column Value". Resulting in something like this:

```
|  Time  | Value  |  Slice_of_Value   | Position | 
|   1    |   100  | [75, 70, … 150]   |        0 | 
|   2    |    75  | [70, 105, … 150]  |        0 |
|   3    |    70  | [105, 140, … 150] |        3 |
|   4    |   105  | [140, 220, … 150] |        2 |
|   5    |   140  | [220, 65, … 150]  |        1 |
|   6    |   220  | [65, 180, 150]    |        0 |
|   7    |    65  | [180, 150]        |     null |
|   8    |   180  | [150]             |        0 |
|   9    |   150  | []                |     null |
```

Now I hurt myself with some issues:

Step 1: `Slice_of_Value`
To get the `Slice_of_Value` column, here is what I have tried at first:

```
df = df.with_columns([
  pl.col("Value").slice(pl.col("Time"), 9).implode().alias("Slice_of_Value")
])
```

but it seems that it is not possible to use `pl.col("")` as part of `.slice()`... So I resorted to do something like this instead:

```
df = df.with_columns(
  [
    pl.col("Value").shift(-i).alias(f"lag_{i}") for i in range(1, 9)
  ]
).with_columns(
  [
    pl.concat_list([f"lag_{i}" for i in range(1, 9)]).alias("Slice_of_Value")
  ]
)
```

So far so good.

Step 2: `Position`

```
df = df.with_columns([
    pl.col("Slice_of_Value")
      .list.eval(pl.arg_where(pl.element() < pl.col("Value")))
      .list.eval(pl.element().first())
      .list.eval(pl.element().drop_nulls())
      .explode()
      .add(pl.col("Time") + 1)
      .alias("NewColumn")
])
```

Unfortunately this piece of code does not work because `named columns are not allowed in arr.eval` ... So I am kinda hitting a wall now. I don't know if my whole approach is wrong or if I have missed something from the docs.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated :)

**EDIT: BENCHMARK RESULTS**

So far I have tried 4 solutions on my real dataset. Here are my benchmarks:

SOLUTION 1: 0.83s for 10M rows

```
lookahead=10
df = dfSource.with_columns(  
      pl.when(pl.col("Value").shift(-i)<pl.col("Value"))
      .then(pl.col("Time").shift(-i)).alias(f"time_{i}") for i in range(1, lookahead+1)
  ).with_columns(
      NewColumn=pl.coalesce(pl.col(f"time_{i}") for i in range(1,lookahead+1))
  ).drop([f"time_{i}" for i in range(1,lookahead+1)]).collect()
```

SOLUTION 2: 3.41s for 10M rows

```
df.groupby_rolling("Time", period=f"{df.height}i", offset="0i").agg(
    x=pl.arg_where(pl.col("Value") < pl.col("Value").first()).first() - 1
)
```

Gave incorrect results, so I transformed it to this:

```
df = df.groupby_dynamic(
  "Time",
  every="1i",
  period="10i",
  include_boundaries=False,
  closed="left",
).agg(
  pl.col("Value").alias("Slices")
).select(
    pl.col("Time"),
    pl.col("Slices")
      .list.eval(pl.arg_where(pl.element() < pl.element().first()))
      .list.get(0)
      .add(pl.col("Time"))
      .alias("NewColumn"),
).collect()
```

SOLUTION 3: (exceeded RAM)

```
df.with_columns(position=pl.col("Value").implode()).with_columns(
    next_time=pl.col("position")
    .list.take(pl.arange(pl.col("Time") - 1, df.height))
    .list.eval(pl.arg_where(pl.element() < pl.element().first()))
    .list.first()
    + pl.col('Time') # +1 and -1 cancel out here.
)
```

Exceeded RAM because of `pl.col("Value").implode()` since it means transposing 10M rows into lists of 10M elements...

So I accepted the `SOLUTION 1` that produced fastest results on real situation and also cleanest code IMHO (no lists, more concise, no need to do further joins...).

Finally, here are some further benchmarks after increasing the lookahead size.

```
Lookahead Size  |  SOLUTION 1 Time  |  SOLUTION 2 Time  |
          10    |           0.83s   |         3.41s     |
          20    |           1.24s   |         3.83s     |
          50    |           2.24s   |         5.34s     |
         100    |           4.45s   |         8.10s     |
         200    |           8.58s   |        17.86s     |
         500    |          20.24s   |        66.93s     |
        1000    |          70.63s   |       108.12s     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way...

```
lookahead=8
(
    df
        .with_columns(  
            pl.when(pl.col("Value").shift(-i)<pl.col("Value"))
            .then(pl.col("Time").shift(-i)).alias(f"time{i}") for i in range(1, lookahead+1)
        )
        .with_columns(
            NewColumn=pl.coalesce(pl.col(f"time{i}") for i in range(1,lookahead+1))
        ).drop([f"time{i}" for i in range(1,lookahead+1)])
)
```

The starting point or strategy is that nested lists are difficult to work with. Usually when facing nested lists you want to find a way to explode them or otherwise not work with them directly. When applying to this scenario, don't make lists, making lists is usually the wrong path unless there's a specific function which easily operates on a list.

What I did instead was to take your starting point of making a generator of a fixed lookahead but instead of having each column be the shifted value, it's the conditional that you're checking for. Instead of returning that value, it returns the time value or null which goes into the next step which is to coalesce all those columns. Lastly, it just drops all the lookahead columns.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer as I was also feeling using lists is not that performant. Let me compare both solutions and I will edit my post with benchmarks before accepting answer. Thanks

Comment: I just remembered this one. It has a way to have the performance scale by gap size rather than df size. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75316374/finding-first-index-of-where-value-in-column-b-is-greater-than-a-value-in-column/75322650#75322650

Answer (score 1):

Here's a workaround for that `arr.eval` issue: include the element in question in the list as the first element, use `pl.element().first` in the `arg_where`, and do a -1 adjustment afterwards.

I also did an alternate way of getting the sublists wanted with `take` and `arange`, but your list comprehension set of expressions is just fine too (and works lazily, I had to use `df.height`!):

```py
df.with_columns(position=pl.col("Value").implode()).with_columns(
    next_time=pl.col("position")
    .list.take(pl.arange(pl.col("Time") - 1, df.height))
    .list.eval(pl.arg_where(pl.element() < pl.element().first()))
    .list.first()
    + pl.col('Time') # +1 and -1 cancel out here.
)
```

```
shape: (9, 3)
┌──────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ Time ┆ Value ┆ next_time│
│ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ i64  ┆ i64   ┆ u32      │
╞══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 1    ┆ 100   ┆ 2        │
│ 2    ┆ 75    ┆ 3        │
│ 3    ┆ 70    ┆ 7        │
│ 4    ┆ 105   ┆ 7        │
│ 5    ┆ 140   ┆ 7        │
│ 6    ┆ 220   ┆ 7        │
│ 7    ┆ 65    ┆ null     │
│ 8    ┆ 180   ┆ 9        │
│ 9    ┆ 150   ┆ null     │
└──────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

This also works only on strictly less / greater than, if equal was matching you'd have to `take` the 2nd `element` `arg_where` ... not an elegant solution IMO, but it is a functional one given the `arr.eval` constraints.

EDIT:

In response to comments below, I tinkered with `groupby_rolling` and by setting the  `offset` to 0, I was able to get the same resulting Series by row to operate on. Let me know if this performs on a real 10M DataFrame - the `period` probably still probably needs a hard constraint is my guess:

```py
df.groupby_rolling("Time", period=f"{df.height}i", offset="0i").agg(
    x=pl.arg_where(pl.col("Value") < pl.col("Value").first()).first() - 1
)
```

(Can join this dataframe to the original on `Time`, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nice workaround with `pl.element().first()` however, my real dataset contains more than 10 million rows, and imploding the whole column will not fit into memory. (I will update my question to specify this). That being said, I think I could limit the `implode()` to the next X elements only, but I wonder if working with lists is a good idea at all? Wouldn't it be possible to use some windowing functions to somehow do the `arg_where()` directly on the column `Value` without prior `implode()`?

Comment: I  thought about windows but not sure with the need to get every element after the first, if it's any faster / memory improving.

Comment: Could the windowing maybe solve the "lower than OR EQUAL"/"greater than OR EQUAL" issue? If you have a window solution I would love to see. For instance is there any equivalent to SQL's `OVER (ROWS BETWEEN 0 PRECEDING and 100 FOLLOWING` using Polars?

Comment: Updated answer, it seems by adjusting the `period` and `offset` arguments on `groupby_rolling` such a groupby is possible (but not in a Polars `over` expression).

Comment: Maybe I did something wrong, but the second code you provided gives incoherent results. For instance, `Time` 8 is null. My guess is that this is due to using `pl.col("Value").first`. But you got me thinking into using `groupyby_dynamic`. And came up with this: ```df = df.groupby_dynamic(
    "Time", every="1i", period="10i", include_boundaries=False,closed="left"
  ).agg(
    pl.col("Value")
  ).with_columns(
    pl.col("Value")
    .list.eval(pl.arg_where(pl.element() < pl.element().first()))
    .list.get(0).add(pl.col('Time'))
    .alias("NewColumn")
  )```